# Postman Chrome: how to use variables from an array for the URL

Tags: arrays, rest, postman

Sorry to bother you, but I really would use some help on the below:

I am using Postman Chrome extension against an Rest API.
My URI is like the following and the request type is PUT:

`PUT https://{{api-fqdn}}/some/path/to/something/ROLE111`

I have about 100 roles with different names.

Instead of passing each time different role name at the end of the URI, how could I use Postman to scan an array and replace all the values inside using a variable, such as `{{rolename}}`?

Comment: It can be done in JMeter, can you consider?

Comment: no, I cannot use that one in this scenario :) but thank you for the suggestion, I would use it for other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at using the native Postman app with the Collection Runner. You can create a data file (either JSON or CSV) with your different role names, The runner will replace that variable placeholder with the data from the file.

More info can be found here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/working-with-data-files/